# Multiprocessing error when get key input with inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, multiprocessing

I am using the module Inputs to get key input in Python when I run this code below

```
import inputs

events = inputs.get_key()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
```

I get this error:

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Exception ignored in: <bound method InputDevice.__del__ of inputs.Keyboard("/dev/input/by-id/usb-A_Nice_Keyboard-event-kbd")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\26099\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\inputs.py", line 2541, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\26099\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 113, in terminate
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'
```

This only happens when i run it in a python file. If i run it in the python shell i don't get this error.

Comment: Move `events = inputs.get_key()` **after** the `freeze_support` line. Basically `freeze_support` should the first thing to be run by your code...

Comment: If I do that I get freeze_support() not defined

Comment: You also need `from multiprocessing import freeze_support`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`freeze_support()` has to be properly imported and be the first thing run. That would look like this:

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import inputs

freeze_support()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    events = inputs.get_key()
```

Comment: I tried putting it in a loop and I cannot get it to work in the loop

Comment: from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import inputs
freeze_support()


while True:
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        events = inputs.get_key()
        print(events)

Comment: I'll need some more detail about that, what error is it throwing and/or how exactly is it failing?

Comment: I don't get a error but when I try type it doesn't print anything

Comment: Try replacing your current print statement with " for event in events: print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)  " , since I'm not sure you can or should print just " events ". If that doesn't work check if  " freeze_support() " is messing anything up by running it with that line commented.

Comment: When trying the code with pygame it creates another window. I know you can get key input with pygame but its slow for how i want to use it

Answer (score 0):

So the answer given by Nathaniel Taulbut was what I needed but it didn't run in a loop which is what I needed so I changed the code a bit to run in a loop.

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
import inputs

freeze_support()

def Keys():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        while True:
            events = inputs.get_key()
            for event in events:
                print(event.code)

Keys()
```

As far as I have tested it works but is there a way I could get this code working without `if __name__ == '__main__'`

Comment: The `if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom should be put at the top level of the file. For example `import inputs, multiprocessing <newline> def Keys(): ... <newline> if __name__ == '__main__': <newline>multiprocessing.freeze_support(); Keys()`. Note that it is needed due to limitations in the Windows OS. In linux you don't need to use that `if` when using `multiprocessing`.